# How to change orientation in android only when it is enabled?

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

In my android app, i have an activity that comes both in portrait and landscape modes. Here's how it's done:

In my manifest, for the activity i have set

`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|locale"`

and `onConfigurationChanged` method in my activity

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        //handling the change
}
```

the problem is, even when my device screen rotation is disabled, the app does switch to landscape mode when i turn it. How do i tell it to listen the device screen mode?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

In your manifest you have registered to listen to config changes. But if you don't want landscape mode, you may try above line of code.

I think, Following would fulfill your requirement.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Landscape");
        if (allowPortraitOnly) {
            Log.d(TAG, "portrait only is allowed, changing to portrait");
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Portrait");
    }
}
```

We check for device orientation primarily at run time. Auto rotation is enabled in the settings.
For instance we want to restrict device only with portrait mode. With a boolean variable (or something else like shared preferences) allowPortraitOnly = 'true' value, we do this. 
When device changes to landscape mode, we get onConfigurationChanged() invoked and manually change device to portrait mode.

Please note that you must include following in manifest.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: I do want landscape mode,but only when user has allowed it

Answer (score 0):

you need

```
android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

in your manifest:
then  Override onConfigurationChanged()

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 //here you can handle orientation change
}
```

then  Add this line to your activity's onCreate()

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

as answered by @Jose.

**Remember** using `android:screenOrientation="nosensor"` this you will  not be able to handle orientation changes at all.

Comment: But OP does want to handle orientation changes.